# C# query datetime off sqlite database fails

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am reading a sqlite file in which datetime column data are saved as integer values (INTEGER NO NULL)

```
DateTime dt=reader.GetDateTime(nColDateTime);
```

But it emits an error saying that the return value is not in correct format. 
I try out all other available methods in Datetime class and find only

```
DateTime dt=DateTime.FromBinary(reader.GetInt64(nColDateTime));
```

works (as others return exceptions). 
But the formatted date (as dt.ToShortDateTime()) is incorrect (ie 0042/11/20) I have no idea what this is.
I then try this

```
long d=DateTime.Now.Ticks-reader.GetInt64(nColDateTime);
DateTime dt=new DateTime(d);
```

It gives me 1970/05/18

Could you help me to get the correct datetime ?

Comment: Well you're presumably along the right lines with GetInt64, but you need to know what the integer *means*. Do you have some sample values along with the date/time they're meant to represent?

Comment: Thanks, for your interest, 123958450000000000000, just an example.

Comment: @Jon, since he shows that subtracting the number from `DateTime.Now.Ticks` gives a date near 1970, we can assume that this is using the Unix epoch.

Comment: @Sesama: That number won't fit in an Int64, so I don't think that is a valid value.

Comment: +1 for you, and Be easy please, as I said it was just an example. huhu, I just lost my school basics, if I could get back to fill this up and above all formally certified as I fking lost it, I won't make this question. huhu,

Comment: @SesamaSesame: It needs to be a *valid* example. You can't just give us any number and claim that's an example - we need an example of an actual, *real* number in your database, and the date/time it's meant to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are stored in the Unix epoch format.

You probably just want to use:

```
private static readonly DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

...

var myDate = epoch + TimeSpan.FromTicks(reader.GetInt64(nColDateTime));
```

---

For example, when I look at your example above "1970/05/18", I can assume that your date is approximately 5 months, 18 days earlier than today.

Here is how I would retreieve the original value:

```
(DateTime.Today - new DateTime(1970, 5, 18)).Ticks
```

Which returns:

```
13119840000000000
```

Plugging that into my formula:

```
new DateTime(1970, 1, 1) + TimeSpan.FromTicks(13119840000000000)
```

This returns:

```
2011/07/30
```

Comment: Thank you Smarty John Gietzen, where can I find information of datetime remarks on different systems ?

Comment: @Sesama: I don't really know.  Just ask questions that you may have here on Stack Overfow.